# React Context not passing data to its child components

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am a beginner in React. Looking at a few medium articles and React docs(which is complicated) I have tried to implement this very basic **Context API**.
I have missed some basic point which is the reason why I haven't got the correct result which is to pass data through the components tree and access them in the child component.
Please let me know how to **correct** **given code snippet** and what have I missed.

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';

const AppContext = React.createContext();

function GreenBox () {
  return <div className='green-box'>
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => context.value}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  </div>
}
function BlueBox () {
  return <div className='blue-box'><GreenBox/></div>
}
class RedBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className='red-box'>
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => context.value}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
      <BlueBox/>
      </div>
  }
}

class Context extends React.Component {
  state = {
    number: 10
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value = {this.state.number}>
        <RedBox/>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default Context;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you set in the `Provider` will be the argument received in the render props function in `Consumer`, so instead of accessing the number you're expecting  with `context.value`, you should just change to `context`.